# Check state of button in tkinter

Tags: python, button, canvas, tkinter, bind

On a tkinter GUI I want to print different messages on a canvas depending on the state of a button I hover over. If the button itself is DISABLED, I want to display another message on the canvas than when the button is NORMAL.
I have this (stripped) relevant code:

```
from tkinter import *

class app:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.button = Button(self.window,text="Button",command=self.someCommand,state=DISABLED)

        self.button.bind("<Enter>", self.showText)
        self.button.bind("<Leave>", self.hideText)

        self.window.mainloop()

    def showText(self):
        if self.button["state"] == DISABLED:
            #print this text on a canvas
        else:
            #print that text on a canvas

    def hideText(self):
        #remove text    

def main()
    instance = app()

main()
```

This always draws 'that text' on the canvas, instead of 'this text'

I have tried the following too:

```
 self.button['state']
 == 'disabled'
 == 'DISABLED'
```

if I print:

```
print(self.button["state"] == DISABLED)
```

it gives me:

```
False
```

Changing the state using:

```
self.button["state"] = NORMAL
```

works as I would expect.

I have read through a few topics here but none seem to answer the question to why the if-statement doesn't work.

Answer (score 15):

After some more research I finally got a solution.

```
print(self.button['state'])
```

prints:

```
disabled
```

So I could use:

```
state = str(self.button['state'])
if state == 'disabled':
    #print the correct text!
```

Comment: super easy way to do it! Thanks for that, saved me a lot of time

Comment: Note: `self.button['state']` does not return a string. Instead, it returns `<class '_tkinter.Tcl_Obj'>`

Answer (score 0):

State returns the **string** only. And also for me `if state == DISABLED:` works fine.

Only difference is I'm not using this inside class: But inside my main program.

Please refer below screen shot:

[image: state]

Answer (score -1):

```
from tkinter import *
app_win  = Tk()

name_btn = Button(app_win,text = 'aaaaaaa')
name_btn.pack()


print(name_btn["state"])
#normal

app_win.mainloop()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).